# Connecting to OpenID using PHP cURL Showing Error

Tags: php, curl, oauth, openid, identityserver3

I am using the following code to request a token from a IdentityServer, which uses OpenID protocol:

```
$curl = curl_init( 'https://remoteserver.com/connect/token' ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$code = $_GET['code'];  // The code from the previous request
$redirect_uri = 'http://mycalldomain.com/test.php';

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
) );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,
    "MYCLIENTID" . ":" . 
    "MYCLIENTSECRET");

$auth = curl_exec( $curl ); 
print '$auth = ';print_r($auth); // to see the error
$secret = json_decode($auth); 
$access_key = $secret->access_token;
```

Is outputing the following error:

```
$auth = {"ErrorMessage":"Unsupported Mediatype"}
```

Can someone guide on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a Content-Type HTTP header that the resource you're POSTing things accepts, by adding something like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```

That will make it JSON (as an example!), and your output data (CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS) must correspond to the Content-Type you choose.

Currently, the Content-Type is "multipart/form-data", as per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.

If you want to use the Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", then in addition to setting that as the Content-Type, you have to give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS in that format too. Being a web development language, PHP has a built-in function [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for encoding arrays in that format:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
)));
```

Comment: I have set it, but still returning the same error. From further investigation, it appears that the value should not be in json - http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest

Comment: Can you help me to reformat my code, as not sure how I can send with the following type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: I edited the answer to have an example for that, as well. In general, when doing POSTs, one should always be sure not only of the expected Content-Type, but also what format the POSTed data is in. Many libraries will have default values for it, so the format may not be obvious from the code if not explicitly set.